# Without any modification in SNMP Agent code I want to send trap by just modifying MIB

Tags: java, snmp

Is there any way like without modifying my SNMP Agent code, i just modify the MIB (like adding some parameter or variables into it) & from that i'll be able to send trap with modified MIB without doing any SNMP Agent code change?

Comment: Does your agent already send traps, or just SNMP messages?  If just messages, I suspect not: messages are sent over UDP port 161, traps over UDP port 162.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want cannot be achieved, as MIB documents are only a contract between the agent and the managers. When you receive a MIB document, the agent has already implemented it, and even if you modify the document that contract inside the agent never changes.

I would be surprised if you were the developer of that agent, as in that case you should have known how a MIB document is used during the agent development, and you should know modifying it alone won't affect the agent.

Comment: Thanks Lex for your help i really appreciate it. Actually i just want to assured myself on this like, it might be possible that some people had tried that & it may be possible that they know the way how to do this & all. But apart from this i really want some more help from you on snmp4j like "How MIB & SNMP Agent can integrate in java so that MIB & SNMP Agent can communicate with each other"

Comment: If you do have questions about snmp4j, you have to start from its wiki first, https://oosnmp.net/confluence/display/SNMP4J/Home. If that's not enough, your only hope is to digest the source code or check its mailing list archive, http://www.snmp4j.org/ where you might find useful information.